# Team Foundation Build - resolving cross solution project references

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

We have a shared project referenced across multiple solutions which, when encountered by TF build causes:

'error MSB3202: The project file "......\trunk\\\sharedproject.csproj" was not found'.

This is fine as the directory structure on the build server does not reflect that of source control.  Is it possible to modify the build file to search in a specific location for this project?

Comment: I ended up replicating the directory structure in the working tree on the server.  I'll update this if/when I find a build config work around.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider adding a dll reference to the shared project instead of a project reference, and then include the dll in your source control. If that is not an option, you could always create another solution file that references the correct path of the share project file on your build server, and use that solution on your build server. I'm inclined to the dll reference though, since option two is harder to maintain in the long run.

Hope it helps.

/Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the Workspace tab in the build definition.

My solution file references projects that are outside of the current project, such as a $/Common project.

For an automated build to work, the workspace on the build agent needed to be correctly mapped. Looking at the error generated, I could determine where the folders were expected to be.

So my Working Folders has a few different projects listed in it, with the Build Agent Folder being the location on the Build Agent computer, not my local computer (that threw me for a loop). Everything is built on the build agent, and then copied to an output directory.